# Convert key-value pairs back to normal tables

Tags: sql, key-value

My boss asked me to convert tables to key-value pairs. So instead of

```
id a  b  c
1  a1 b1 c1
2  a2 b2 c2
3  a3 b3 c3
```

We have

```
id col val
1  a   a1
1  b   b1
1  c   c1
2  a   a2
2  b   b2
2  c   c2
3  a   a3
3  b   b3
3  c   c3
```

Now my question is whether it's possible to write an SQL statement to convert the latter table back to the former. My guess is that it can't be done. But will I offend my boss if I tell him so?

Comment: Try searching for "unpivot" you'll find thousands of possibilities.

Comment: Try searching `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`MAX`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) to pivot the `val` column into three separate columns (a, b, and c), depending on the value in the `col` column:

```
CREATE TABLE transformed (
  id INT,
  col CHAR(1),
  val VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO transformed (id, col, val) VALUES
(1, 'a', 'a1'),
(1, 'b', 'b1'),
(1, 'c', 'c1'),
(2, 'a', 'a2'),
(2, 'b', 'b2'),
(2, 'c', 'c2'),
(3, 'a', 'a3'),
(3, 'b', 'b3'),
(3, 'c', 'c3');

SELECT 
  id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 'a' THEN val END) AS a,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 'b' THEN val END) AS b,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 'c' THEN val END) AS c
FROM transformed
GROUP BY id;
```

**Output:**

```
id  a   b   c
1   a1  b1  c1
2   a2  b2  c2
3   a3  b3  c3
```

Try on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d3ff4a/5).

Comment: `ELSE NULL` is not necessary and can be omitted since that's the default behavior for the `CASE` clause.

Comment: Made the change.